# Cannot invoke method snackbarWithMessage with an argument list

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I can't understand why my method call is incorrect.
I'm trying to use SSSnackbar for ios with swift. It has method with the following signature:

```
@implementation SSSnackbar
+ (instancetype)snackbarWithMessage:(NSString *)message
                         actionText:(NSString *)actionText
                           duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                        actionBlock:(void (^)(SSSnackbar *sender))actionBlock
                     dismissalBlock:(void (^)(SSSnackbar *sender))dismissalBlock {
```

My call of this method:

```
var bar = SSSnackbar.snackbarWithMessage("Success auth" as NSString,
        actionText: "Ok" as NSString, duration : NSTimeInterval(5),
        actionBlock: {(sender: SSSnackbar) -> () in 
            println("Snackbar action")
        }, dismissalBlock:nil)
```

Documentations says that dismissalBlock can be nil. 
Compile error: `Error:(48, 38) cannot invoke 'snackbarWithMessage' with an argument list of type '(NSString, actionText: NSString, duration: Double, actionBlock: (SSSnackbar) -> (), dismissalBlock: nil)'`

I tried without casting `String` to `NSString`, with not `nil` dismissalBlock

UPD: I have fixed this:

```
var bar = SSSnackbar(message:"Success auth", actionText: "Ok", duration : NSTimeInterval(5) ,
                    actionBlock: {snackbar in println("clicked")}, dismissalBlock:nil)
```

Comment: You are permitted on StackOverflow to answer your own question.  Please move your update to an answer.

Comment: Something else to check which can trip you up is `optionals` in callbacks. Your method might be getting the error due to `(sender: SSSnackbar)` not being `(sender: SSSnackbar!)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue:

```
var bar = SSSnackbar(message:"Success auth", actionText: "Ok", duration : NSTimeInterval(5) ,
                actionBlock: {snackbar in println("clicked")}, dismissalBlock:nil)
```

I don't understand why I should call it with constructor instead of call it as static class member, but it seems to be the same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459730/how-to-call-objective-c-instancetype-method-in-swift).